# Deleting NSUserdefault Array from a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array which saves all the user inputs as an array of Strings using NSUserDefaults. In another view controller this array data can be viewed in a UITableView. Is there any way to delete the record in the array when I delete a row in the UITableView?

please refer the following for more detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679088/tableview-nsinternalinconsistency-exception-error

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Apple documentation NSUserDefaults Class Reference "Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable"

Answer (score 0):

try like this in your tableview delete function

```
 NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SavedArray"];
[dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:yourIndex];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setValue:dataArray forKey:@"SavedArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Using this code you will delete or resave your array in userdefaults

Answer (score 0):

In your didSelect

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a three step process:

**Step 1:** Fetch & save your user details in a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *userDetailsArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userDetails"] mutableCopy];
```

**Step 2:** Update your data array once user delete something. Use any of the below methods:

```
[userDetailsArray removeObject:<Your_Object>];
[userDetailsArray removeObjectAtIndex:<Your_Index>];
```

**Step 3:** Finally save them back in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userDetailsArray forKey:@"userDetails"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all NSUser defaults just use :-

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
```